# Python Newbie, what is this error? (Pip Install Pywin32)

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to get this module installed however it seems there's some issue. Is anyone able to make sense of what is happening?

```
H:\>pip install pywin32
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/pywin32/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/pywin32/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/pywin32/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/pywin32/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)'))': /simple/pywin32/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pywin32/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pywin32/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

Comment: Maybe you are using a VPN, which is causing SSL error.

Comment: try set `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` env variable to custom cert path

Comment: @ShivamMiglani Its over my work network so I suspect that is the issue...

Comment: @rv.kvetch would you be able to expand? Not really following what you're saying!

Comment: just set coresponding env var, i think it should work. i would se tit in `env`. then to path of cert pem file on local drive, if you do have one i mean.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? The URL you show above does not use a self-signed certificate, yet this is what your system reports. This happens typically when a proxy is in the middle and replace the certificate with its own, a self-signed one, and this is often reported as not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Specify Python Interpreter**

Try running the below command by appending the Python command to it. This will ensure the correct Python interpreter is specified and the packages will be installed over there.

**If you are using Python 3:**

```
python3 -m pip install [package_name]
```

**If you are using Python 2:**

```
python -m pip install [package_name]
```